# error when running expo and starting a new project

Tags: react-native, expo

[cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/var/run/watchman/ElroyFernandes-state/sock! (No such file or directory)

Watchman:  watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr= 2017-10-24T07:57:59,796: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/var/run/watchman/ElroyFernandes-state/sock! (No such file or directory)

jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.

Error: watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr= 2017-10-24T07:57:59,796: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/var/run/watchman/ElroyFernandes-state/sock! (No such file or directory)

[cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/var/run/watchman/ElroyFernandes-state/sock! (No such file or directory)

watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr=

[cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/var/run/watchman/ElroyFernandes-state/sock! (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure your watchman is the latest?